# google sdk not installed after uninstall

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to install google cloud sdk in windows machine it was working fine first time, due to other reasons I uninstalled and trying to install again now it is not allowing to install showing error that

"Error:(gcloud.components.update) failed to fetch component listing from server...

https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/GoogleCloudSDKInstaller.exe

os :windows 10

kindly help on this.

Comment: Hello Rathakrishnan, could you please specify if your Windows machine is *on-premise* or in the *cloud* (e.g. a Compute Engine instance)? What **version of the Google Cloud SDK** are you trying to install? Is it the latest one? Also, what **version of Python** do you have installed on your machine? At which **step** does the installation fail?

Comment: thank you Denis from here 
 downloaded the latest version ttps://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/GoogleCloudSDKInstaller.exe

on prime system :windows 10   ,    I tried with python 3.8.2 version but its getting failed in installation step itself ..

Comment: According to the [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install), Cloud SDK supports Python versions **3.5** to **3.7**, and **2.7.9** or higher.